# Send mail with SendGrid and null values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, email, sendgrid

Iam using SendGrid in asp.net C#. I have this function to send mail

```
public async Task SendMail(string AddTo, string Addcc, string Subject, string Message)
{
    var myMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();
    myMessage.AddTo(AddTo);
    myMessage.AddCc(Addcc);
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@noreply.se");
    myMessage.Subject = Subject;
    myMessage.Html = Message;

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
       );
    //Some validation code
}
```

I need do add `AddCc` to some mail but not all. This works fine.

```
SendMail("mailadress1@gmail.com", "mailadress2@gmail.com", "Subject", "Message");
```

But not this if don't want to send CC

```
SendMail("mailadress1@gmail.com", "null", "Subject", "Message");
```

or this

```
SendMail("mailadress1@gmail.com", "", "Subject", "Message");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it by setting a default value and check if `AddCc` is `null`:

```
public async Task SendMail(string AddTo, string Addcc = null, string Subject, string Message)
{
    var myMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();
    myMessage.AddTo(AddTo);
    if(AddCc != null)
    {
        myMessage.AddCc(Addcc);
    }
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@noreply.se");
    myMessage.Subject = Subject;
    myMessage.Html = Message;

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
       );
    //Some validation code
}
```

With this you are able to call it like:

```
SendMail("mailadress1@gmail.com", "mailadress2@gmail.com", "Subject", "Message");
```

And without cc:

```
SendMail("mailadress1@gmail.com", "Subject", "Message");
```

You can even do:

```
SendMail("mailadress1@gmail.com", null, "Subject", "Message");
```